# Passing Dict of Arrays using Ajax and Django

Tags: python, arrays, ajax, django

I have a `dictionary of arrays` that I would like to pass to my Django view.

```
       $.ajax({
            url: '/fund_monitor/fund_directory',
            type: 'GET',
            data:{
                filter_dict: filter_dict,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(filter_dict);
            }
        });
```

And in my view I would like to receive this dict:

```
    if request.is_ajax():
        filter_dict = request.GET.getlist('filter_dict')
        print("Is Ajax", filter_dict)
```

But `"Is Ajax []"` gets printed out and just as an example, my `filter_dict`:

```
Designated Broker:["BMO"]
Fund Class:["OM"]
```

Any ideas why a blank array gets passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/fund_monitor/fund_directory',
            type: 'GET',
            data:JSON.stringify({
                filter_dict: filter_dict,
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(filter_dict);
            }
        });


if request.is_ajax():
    request_data = json.loads(request.GET)

    filter_dict = request_data['filter_dict']
    print("Is Ajax", filter_dict)
```